# Open source html parsing class not properly parsing spaces between paragraphs

Tags: objective-c, html-parsing

I'm using an open source method that parses the html text into an NSString.

The resulting strings have large amounts of white space between the first couple of paragraphs, but only one line of space for subsequent paragraphs. Here is an example of an output.

[image]
Below is the method I'm calling. I've only changed two lines of the code. For `stopCharacters` and `newLineAndWhitespaceCharacters`, I removed `/n` from the characterset because when it was included, the entire text was one long paragraph.

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText {

    // Pool
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Character sets
    NSCharacterSet *stopCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"< \t\r%C%C%C%C", 0x0085, 0x000C, 0x2028, 0x2029]];
    NSCharacterSet *newLineAndWhitespaceCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" \t\r%C%C%C%C", 0x0085, 0x000C, 0x2028, 0x2029]];
    NSCharacterSet *tagNameCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];

    // Scan and find all tags
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:self.length];
    NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:self];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
    [scanner setCaseSensitive:YES];
    NSString *str = nil, *tagName = nil;
    BOOL dontReplaceTagWithSpace = NO;
    do {

        // Scan up to the start of a tag or whitespace
        if ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:stopCharacters intoString:&str]) {
            [result appendString:str];
            str = nil; // reset
        }

        // Check if we've stopped at a tag/comment or whitespace
        if ([scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:NULL]) {

            // Stopped at a comment or tag
            if ([scanner scanString:@"!--" intoString:NULL]) {

                // Comment
                [scanner scanUpToString:@"-->" intoString:NULL];
                [scanner scanString:@"-->" intoString:NULL];

            } else {

                // Tag - remove and replace with space unless it's
                // a closing inline tag then dont replace with a space
                if ([scanner scanString:@"/" intoString:NULL]) {

                    // Closing tag - replace with space unless it's inline
                    tagName = nil; dontReplaceTagWithSpace = NO;
                    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:tagNameCharacters intoString:&tagName]) {
                        tagName = [tagName lowercaseString];
                        dontReplaceTagWithSpace = ([tagName isEqualToString:@"a"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"b"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"i"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"q"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"span"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"em"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"strong"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"cite"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"abbr"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"acronym"] ||
                                                   [tagName isEqualToString:@"label"]);
                    }

                    // Replace tag with string unless it was an inline
                    if (!dontReplaceTagWithSpace && result.length > 0 && ![scanner isAtEnd]) [result appendString:@" "];

                }

                // Scan past tag
                [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];
                [scanner scanString:@">" intoString:NULL];

            }

        } else {

            // Stopped at whitespace - replace all whitespace and newlines with a space
            if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:newLineAndWhitespaceCharacters intoString:NULL]) {
                if (result.length > 0 && ![scanner isAtEnd]) [result appendString:@" "]; // Dont append space to beginning or end of result
            }

        }

    } while (![scanner isAtEnd]);

    // Cleanup
    [scanner release];

    // Decode HTML entities and return
    NSString *retString = [[result stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] retain];
    [result release];

    // Drain
    [pool drain];

    // Return
    return [retString autorelease];

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the NSLog of the string. I only pasted the first few paragraphs

```
Mitt Romney spent the past six years running for president. After his loss to President Barack Obama, he'll have to chart a different course.  


 His initial plan: spend time with his family. He has five sons and 18 grandchildren, with a 19th on the way.  






 "I don't look at postelection to be a time of regrouping. Instead it's a time of forward focus," Romney told reporters aboard his plane Tuesday evening as he returned to Boston after the final campaign stop of his political career. "I have, of course, a family and life important to me, win or lose."  

 The most visible member of that family — wife Ann Romney — says neither she nor her husband will seek political office again.
```

etc....

```
for (int j = 25; j< 50; j++) {
    char test =  [completeTrimmed characterAtIndex:([completeTrimmed rangeOfString:@"chart a different course."].location + j)];

        NSLog(@"%hhd", test);
    }

012-11-11 17:15:57.668 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.669 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.669 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 10
2012-11-11 17:15:57.670 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.670 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.670 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 10
2012-11-11 17:15:57.671 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.671 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.671 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 10
2012-11-11 17:15:57.672 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.672 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 72
2012-11-11 17:15:57.672 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 105
2012-11-11 17:15:57.673 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 115
2012-11-11 17:15:57.673 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.673 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 105
2012-11-11 17:15:57.673 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 110
2012-11-11 17:15:57.674 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 105
2012-11-11 17:15:57.674 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 116
2012-11-11 17:15:57.674 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 105
2012-11-11 17:15:57.675 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 97
2012-11-11 17:15:57.675 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 108
2012-11-11 17:15:57.675 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 32
2012-11-11 17:15:57.675 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 112
2012-11-11 17:15:57.676 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 108
2012-11-11 17:15:57.676 LMU_LAL_LAUNCHER[5431:c07] 97
```

Comment: Probably you need to use stringByReplacingCharactersInRange method to remove extra white spaces from the final string.

Comment: I've already tried  `completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"                           " withString:@""];` , but it doesn't do anything

Comment: @" " should have about 15 spaces in between, but the comment autocorrects it to 1 space

Comment: Have you tried with stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet? Check with the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with the question above and this is how I fixed it,

```
NSString *retString = [[result stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] retain];
[result release];

retString = [retString stripDuplicateCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] withString:@" "];
retString = [retString stripDuplicateCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] withString:@"\n"];
```

I have defined a category method on NSString as,

```
- (NSString *)stripDuplicateCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)characterSet withString:(NSString *)joiningString;
```

The implementation is as follows,

```
- (NSString *)stripDuplicateCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)characterSet withString:(NSString *)joiningString {

    NSMutableString *originalStr = [NSMutableString string];

    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSArray *componentsArray = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet];

    int counter = 0;
    for (NSString *stringComponent in componentsArray) {

        counter ++;

        if ((stringComponent) && ([stringComponent length] > 0) && (![stringComponent isEqualToString:@" "]) && ((![stringComponent isEqualToString:@"\n"]) || (![joiningString isEqualToString:@"\n"]))) {

            if ([componentsArray count] == counter) {
                [originalStr appendFormat:@"%@", stringComponent];                
            } else {
                [originalStr appendFormat:@"%@%@", stringComponent, joiningString];
            }
        }
    }

    return originalStr;
}
```

Add the above method in `NSString+HTML.m` file as a category on `NSString`. Basically in the html given by you, white spaces and newline were getting mixed multiple times, and trying to strip newline alone was not working. So I am removing duplicate newlines and white spaces as shown above by comparing if the string has newline or whitespace after stripping and then appending on to main string.

Alternatively, you can also try as,

```
NSString *retString = [[result stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] retain];
[result release];

retString = [retString stripDuplicateNewlineCharacters];
```

The method is defined as,

```
- (NSString *)stripDuplicateNewlineCharacters {

    NSMutableString *originalStr = [NSMutableString string];

    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSArray *componentsArray = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    int counter = 0;
    for (NSString *stringComponent in componentsArray) {

        counter ++;

        stringComponent = [stringComponent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"<#$%$#>"];
        stringComponent = [stringComponent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<#$%$#><#$%$#>" withString:@"<#$%$#>"];
        stringComponent = [stringComponent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<#$%$#>" withString:@" "];

        if ((stringComponent) && ([stringComponent length] > 0) && (![stringComponent isEqualToString:@" "]) && (![stringComponent isEqualToString:@"\n"])) {

            if ([componentsArray count] == counter) {
                [originalStr appendFormat:@"%@", stringComponent];
            } else {
                [originalStr appendFormat:@"%@\n", stringComponent];
            }
        }
    }

    return originalStr;
}
```

In this case, the duplicate white spaces are removed in the method itself while removing new line characters.

Comment: Now it is one long paragraph. I tried removing the `stripDuplicateCharacters` method for whitespaces so only the newline method remains, and the result is one extra line of space after paragraph 1, correct spacing after paragraph 2, and for the remaining paragraphs, the paragraphs start on a new line, but there is no space between the paragraphs.

Comment: I edited the method for the newline characterset, and now all the paragraphs are fine except for 1, which has 1 extra line of space. I removed the condition `(![stringComponent isEqualToString:@" "])`

Comment: @Mahir, That's weird, Because it works fine for me. Can you try adding this `retString = [retString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"**#NEWLINE#**"];` before printing to console and see how many newlines are there between paragraphs?

Comment: I am only calling `retString = [retString stripDuplicateCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] withString:@"\n"];` also

Comment: without calling any of the methods, the pattern is 3 newlines after p1 and 2 after remaining

Comment: @Mahir, I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @Mahir, Check with my answer now. I missed one condition in the if block while cleaning up the code. In case you want more than one newline character between the paragraphs, you can use `retString = [retString stripDuplicateCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] withString:@"\n\n"];`

Comment: It works after I inserted    `completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n " withString:@"\n"];` I realized that the consecutive newlines are separated by either 1 or 2 spaces

Comment: Alternatively, this line of code alone solved the entire thing: `completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n  \n  \n" withString:@"\n\n"];`

Comment: @Mahir, That will not work in all cases. What if the number of spaces in between are not fixed as shown in your example. It will again fail. The above one will work in all the cases and it is more generic. For example "\n\n<><><><>\n<><>\n\n\n<>\n" where <> is a space. This will not work if you use your suggestion. By using my code, this will also be handled.

Answer (score 4):

Check with this,

```
  //Decode HTML entities and return
  NSString *retString = [result stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
  [result release];

  //Drain
  [pool drain];

  retString = [[retString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];

  //Return
  return [retString autorelease];   
}
```

If the above is not working, Also try with

```
completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

and

```
completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
```

Comment: In case it helps, the source code comes from articles like this http://www.laloyolan.com/news/after-defeat-cloudy-future-ahead-for-mitt-romney/article_63f50e24-294e-11e2-a963-001a4bcf6878.html

Comment: I'm using the body paragraphs

Comment: Can you try to print in the console using NSLog and see what are those characters exactly? and what about, completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""]; and completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/r" withString:@""];

Comment: I've added the last two lines -- no change.

I'll post the nslog above

Comment: I once checked to see what the specific space character was and i think it returned char 32. let me double check though

Comment: If it is actual space, it should trim when you call completeTrimmed = [completeTrimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];. Please check if something is wrong, while executing that. Is it normally removing spaces from other strings?

Comment: Ok, so I nslogged the chars for the spaces after the first paragraph, and I'm getting a weird output. I posted the code above.

Comment: Also, I've tried replacing instances of `@" "` with `@""` and it gets rid of all the spaces between words, but not between paragraphs

Comment: @Mahir, Check my other answer. Since your case is different as newline and whitespace characters were getting mixed up. I am keeping this answer here for folks who are facing issue with normal `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` addition to html code.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace @"/n/n" with @"/n" to reduce the number of line breaks.

Comment: I tried `stringByReplacingString:@"/n/n"With:@"/n"` but nothing changed

Comment: I realized that it wasn't working because the consecutive /n characters were separated by a space

Comment: Glad you found the problem. So you can replace "/n /n" with "/n"